# When will spring-XD support the newest version of Apache Spark?

Tags: spring, apache-spark, spring-xd

Current version of spring-xd 1.2.1 as well as snapshot support Spark 1.2.1 released at the beginning of this year (current version is 1.5.1)
Are you going to support new Spark ? When can we expect updated version because now it is very risky to mix spark with Spring-XD without some level of certainty that we will be able to use up to date Spark.

I've tried to run Spring-XD with Spark 1.5.1 unfortunately there were many missing libraries so I've abandoned this idea.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Are you going to support current version of Apache Spark  1.5.1 ?

Comment: Who is? This is not the Spring XD support group. I think you are asking your question on the wrong site.

Comment: This is where Spring redirect me http://spring.io/questions "Welcome to our StackOverflow page, where we maintain a list of StackOverflow tags that our engineering team monitors and participates in." So I hope someone from Spring project look through tagged topics ? Or maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: Ok. Then welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to reformulate your question in a manner that it shouldn't be directed just to Spring engineers. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question. (Remember that this is not a Spring dedicated site, you'll get answers from member of the community of stackoverflow)